# Liferay : Bean Locator has not been set

Tags: service, liferay

I have a existing table in database. I have modified service.xml as follows :-
Service.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE service-builder PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Service Builder 6.0.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-service-builder_6_0_0.dtd">
<service-builder package-path="net.test"> 
    <author>pfeffeg</author>
    <namespace>dataaccess</namespace>
 <entity name="test" remote-service="true" local-service="true">
    <column name="PID" type="long"></column>
    <column name="PName" type="String"></column>
    <column name="IID" type="long" primary="true"></column>
    <column name="iName" type="String"></column>
    </entity>
</service-builder>
```

Create table query:-

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dataaccess_test](
 [PID] [bigint] NULL,
 [PName] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [IID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 [iName] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_IdetailidTest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [IID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,             ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have built the service builder. All classes have apparently been built correctly. but when i try to run the portlet I am getting a Bean Locator exception.

```
BeanLocator has not been set
com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.BeanLocatorException: BeanLocator has not been set
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.PortletBeanLocatorUtil.locate(PortletBeanLocatorUtil.java:40)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks aritzg, I am now able to execute the portlet without errors. The solution -
column name attribute in service.xml should start with a capital letter. Looks strange but it worked for me.

service.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE service-builder PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Service Builder 6.0.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-service-builder_6_0_0.dtd">
<service-builder package-path="net.test"> 
    <author>pfeffeg</author>
    <namespace>dataaccess</namespace>
 <entity name="test" remote-service="true" local-service="true">
    <column name="PID" type="long"></column>
    <column name="PName" type="String"></column>
    <column name="IID" type="long" primary="true"></column>
    <column name="IName" type="String"></column>
    </entity>
</service-builder>
```